# Adding values to different list in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame of fruit names `apple`, `orange`, and `banana`:

```
> fruits
  X.apple. X.orange. X.apple..1 X.banana. X.apple..2  X.orange..1 X.banana..1 
    apple    orange    apple    banana      apple    orange      banana
```

I also have 3 lists: `apples = c()`, `oranges = c()`, and `bananas = c()`. They are simply simply lists.

Now, I want to add in 0/1 value into the list according to the df.
For example:
apple list will become:
`apple = (1,0,1,0,1,0,0)` in which 0 indicate there's no apple at that position of the df.

`oranges = (0,1,0,0,0,1,0)`

`bananas = (0,0,0,1,0,0,1)`

Indeed my original data frame has thousands of elements and hundreds of lists. How can I do this fast?

```
> dput(fruits)
structure(list(X.apple. = structure(1L, .Label = "apple", class = "factor"), 
    X.orange. = structure(1L, .Label = "orange", class = "factor"), 
    X.apple..1 = structure(1L, .Label = "apple", class = "factor"), 
    X.banana. = structure(1L, .Label = "banana", class = "factor"), 
    X.apple..2 = structure(1L, .Label = "apple", class = "factor"), 
    X.orange..1 = structure(1L, .Label = "orange", class = "factor"), 
    X.banana..1 = structure(1L, .Label = "banana", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the unique values of fruits and find the position where they are present.

```
fruits <- unlist(fruits)
unique_fruits <- unique(fruits)
lapply(unique_fruits, function(x) +(fruits == x))

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 0

#[[2]]
#[1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0

#[[3]]
#[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: such an elegant way!

Answer (score 1):

We could do this in a single step with `model.matrix`

```
out <- asplit(model.matrix(~ unlist(fruits) -1), 2)
```